# extract the tftp server address from dhcp ack

Tags: bash-scripting, openwrt, tftp

I'm having a router running `OpenWrt` and tinkering with it.

`Udhcpc` is the `DHCP` client running inside. I'm looking at `/lib/netifd/proto/dhcp.sh` (This script calls udhcpc).

My `DHCP` server has been configured to send option 150 (i.e TFTP server address) whenever a `DHCP` request comes in.

On the `DHCP` client, I would like to extract the `TFTP` server address once the `DHCP` ack is received on the router, and store it in a variable.

Can someone help me to understand what can be done in `dhcp.sh` about this?